# Restrict retrofit from encoding the http request body

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am trying to pass a string as a body of the HTTP POST REQUEST but retrofit encodes my body so that

> / becomes %2F

and `:// becomes %3A%2F%2F`. And I end up with a string which actually looks like this:

**

```
/TRA became %2FTRA
://www.sample.com became %3A%2F%2Fwww.sample.com
```

**

How can I retrain to /TRA and ://www.sample.com

My retrofit rest api is defined as follows:-

```
public interface NetworkCall {
    @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST(HTTPPOSTREQUEST)
        void httppostrequest(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type, @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                             @Field("grant_type") String grant_type, @Field("code") String code,
                             @Field("realm") String realm, @Field("redirect_uri") String redirect_uri,
                             Callback<SmartPassResponse> callback);
}
```

And this is how I am making the

> Retrofit Instance

```
 public static NetworkCall getInstanceSmartPass() {
        RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic YWJzaGVyOkhxfjJhajpkfWtrNGRm");
            }
        };

        if (REST_CLIENT == null) {
            OkHttpClient.Builder b = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            b.readTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            b.writeTimeout(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            OkHttpClient client = b.build();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
            RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                    .setEndpoint(SMARTPASSURL)
                    .setClient(new Ok3Client(client))
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                    .build();
            REST_CLIENT = restAdapter.create(NetworkCall.class);
        }
```

Comment: http:// www.sample.com are you saving this in String ?

Comment: @Syed Hamza Hassan:- yes i am saving this in string

Comment: How you are making call share code ?

Comment: @Syed Hamza:- couldnt get you...

Comment: Show how you are making retrofit instance?

Comment: @Syed:- I have edited my question and below you can also find the code for retrofit Instance

Comment: Share Post url with dummy parameter i need to check your request in Advance Rest Client